# Creating a variable depending on values of two different parameters

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a question regarding how to craft a variable depending on two other variables. I need to create a dummy variable that will take the value of 1 if
`Parameter1` is either A or B (but not C) and `Parameter2` has a positive value. The variable needs both assumptions to upheld, otherwise will take the value of zero. This will be categorized by countries.

I have tried to illustrate this down below. What I am looking for is how to compute a variable that calculates the variable 'Result'.

```
read.table(
text =
"Country, Year, Parameter1, Parameter2, Result,
US, 1, A, 12, 1,
US, 2, B, 4, 1,
US, 3, C, 2, 0,
US, 4, A, -4, 0,
UK, 1, A, -1, 0,
UK, 2, C, 2, 0,
UK, 3, B, 3, 1,
UK, 4, B, 2, 1, ", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

|  | Country | Year | Parameter1 | Parameter2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 1 | A | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | US | 2 | B | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | US | 3 | C | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | US | 4 | A | -4 | 0 |
| 5 | UK | 1 | A | -1 | 0 |
| 6 | UK | 2 | C | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | UK | 3 | B | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | UK | 4 | B | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may create the condition with `%in%` and `&`, coerce the logical to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
df1$Result <- with(df1, +(Parameter1 %in% c("A", "B") & Parameter2 > 0))
df1$Result
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is:

```r
within(df, Result <- as.numeric(!(Parameter1 == 'C' | Parameter2 < 0)))
  Country Year Parameter1 Parameter2 Result
1      US    1          A         12      1
2      US    2          B          4      1
3      US    3          C          2      0
4      US    4          A         -4      0
5      UK    1          A         -1      0
6      UK    2          C          2      0
7      UK    3          B          3      1
8      UK    4          B          2      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach by multiplying the conditions; I am using `dplyr` and `magrittr` packages just for a different look but this can be also applied in the `base` solutions provided by others.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)


df1 %<>% 
  mutate(Result = (Parameter1 != "C") * (Parameter2 > 0))
```

```
#>   Country Year Parameter1 Parameter2 Result
#> 1      US    1          A         12      1
#> 2      US    2          B          4      1
#> 3      US    3          C          2      0
#> 4      US    4          A         -4      0
#> 5      UK    1          A         -1      0
#> 6      UK    2          C          2      0
#> 7      UK    3          B          3      1
#> 8      UK    4          B          2      1
```

##### Data:

```
read.table(
  text =
"Country,Year,Parameter1,Parameter2,Result
US,1,A,12,1
US,2,B,4,1
US,3,C,2,0
US,4,A,-4,0
UK,1,A,-1,0
UK,2,C,2,0
UK,3,B,3,1
UK,4,B,2,1",sep=",",header=TRUE)->df1
```